# How to auto log every request in .NET Core WebAPI?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, .net-core, log4net

I'd like to have every request logged automatically. In previous .Net Framwork WebAPI project, I used to register a delegateHandler to do so.

WebApiConfig.cs

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MessageHandlers.Add(new AutoLogDelegateHandler());
}
```

AutoLogDelegateHandler.cs

```
public class AutoLogDelegateHandler : DelegatingHandler
{

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var requestBody = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;

                //Log use log4net
                _LogHandle(request, requestBody, response);

                return response;
            });
    }
}
```

an example of the log content:

```
------------------------------------------------------
2017-08-02 19:34:58,840
uri: /emp/register
body: {
    "timeStamp": 1481013427,
    "id": "0322654451",
    "type": "t3",
    "remark": "system auto reg"
}
response: {"msg":"c556f652fc52f94af081a130dc627433","success":"true"}
------------------------------------------------------
```

But in .NET Core WebAPI project, there is no `WebApiConfig` , or the register function at Global.asax `GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);`

So is there any way to achieve that in .NET Core WebAPI?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create your own filter attribute...

```
public class InterceptionAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
    var x = "This is my custom line of code I need executed before any of the controller actions, for example log stuff";
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
  }
}
```

... and you would register it with GlobalFilters, but since you said you're using .NET Core, this is how you can try proceeding...

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution):

> You can register a filter globally (for all controllers and actions)
>   by adding it to the MvcOptions.Filters collection in the 
>   ConfigureServices method in the Startup class:

Let us know if it worked.

P.S.
Here's a [whole tutorial on intercepting requests with WebAPI](http://irhadbabic.com/how-to-intercept-all-incoming-requests-with-webapi/), in case someone needs more details.

Comment: Yes, it works. I create an `AutoLogAttribute` ,  and logged every request at `OnActionExecuted`. Then register the filter globallyby adding it to the MvcOptions.Filters collection in the ConfigureServices method in the Startup class.

Comment: @Eedoh How did you do that?

Comment: FYI: Only logs the api part of the app, see graphic below.

Answer (score 47):

`ActionFilter` will work until you need to log **only** requests processed by MVC middleware (as controller actions).

If you need logging for all incoming requests, then you need to use a middleware approach.

Good visual [explanation](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-middleware-as-mvc-filters-in-asp-net-core-1-1/):
[image]

Note that middleware order is important, and if your logging should be done at the start of pipeline execution, your middleware should be one of the first one.

Simple example from [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            // Do loging
            // Do work that doesn't write to the Response.
            await next.Invoke();
            // Do logging or other work that doesn't write to the Response.
        });
```

Comment: Does this work on if my api is running on AWS Api Gateway ... here is my question and i need some help ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59167427/httpcontext-request-is-blank-for-a-middleware-running-on-aws-api-gateway

Comment: I think what you mean is ActionFilter will only work for logging requests processed by the MVC middleware?

Answer (score 15):

For someone that wants a quick and (very) dirty solution for debugging purposes (that works on .Net Core 3), here's an expansion of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45480650/564479) that's all you need...

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    var initialBody = context.Request.Body;

    using (var bodyReader = new StreamReader(context.Request.Body))
    {
        string body = await bodyReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(body);
        context.Request.Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body));
        await next.Invoke();
        context.Request.Body = initialBody;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain the reasoning behind the body content manipulations here?

Comment: @GGleGrand It's been a while but I'm guessing it's because the code was attempting to read the stream twice--once for logging it in here and once "for real". So I needed to reset the stream after I had logged it.

Answer (score 7):

Demo:

AutologArribute.cs (new file)

```
/// <summary>
/// <see cref="https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#Dependency injection"/>
/// </summary>
public class AutoLogAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
    {
        public AutoLogAttribute() : base(typeof(AutoLogActionFilterImpl))
        {

        }

        private class AutoLogActionFilterImpl : IActionFilter
        {
            private readonly ILogger _logger;
            public AutoLogActionFilterImpl(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
            {
                _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AutoLogAttribute>();
            }

            public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
            {
                // perform some business logic work
            }

            public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
            {
                //TODO: log body content and response as well
                _logger.LogDebug($"path: {context.HttpContext.Request.Path}"); 
            }
        }
    }
```

StartUp.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //....

    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters#filter-scopes-and-order-of-execution
    services.AddMvc(opts=> {
        opts.Filters.Add(new AutoLogAttribute());
    });

    //....
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Starting with ASP.NET Core 6 you can use default middleware for such behaviour ([source](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-4/#http-logging-middleware)):

```cs
// ConfigureServices
services.AddHttpLogging()

// Configure
app.UseHttpLogging();
```

Comment: I get `System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.Extensions.ObjectPool.ObjectPool'1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingInterceptorContext]' while attempting to activate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpLogging.HttpLoggingMiddleware'.`

Comment: Please read this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/51322
Try to add `services.AddHttpLogging()` before calling method in an answer

Answer (score 6):

This is a complete Log component for .NET Core 2.2 Web API.
It will log Requests and Responses, both Headers and Bodies.
Just make sure you have a "Logs" folder.

AutoLogMiddleWare.cs (New file)

```
public class AutoLogMiddleWare
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public AutoLogMiddleWare(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            string route = context.Request.Path.Value;
            string httpStatus = "0";

            // Log Request
            var originalRequestBody = context.Request.Body;
            originalRequestBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            string requestBody = new StreamReader(originalRequestBody).ReadToEnd();
            originalRequestBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            // Log Response
            string responseBody = string.Empty;
            using (var swapStream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                var originalResponseBody = context.Response.Body;
                context.Response.Body = swapStream;
                await _next(context);
                swapStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                responseBody = new StreamReader(swapStream).ReadToEnd();
                swapStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                await swapStream.CopyToAsync(originalResponseBody);
                context.Response.Body = originalResponseBody;
                httpStatus = context.Response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }

            // Clean route
            string cleanRoute = route;
            foreach (var c in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
            {
                cleanRoute = cleanRoute.Replace(c, '-');
            }

            StringBuilder sbRequestHeaders = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in context.Request.Headers)
            {
                sbRequestHeaders.AppendLine(item.Key + ": " + item.Value.ToString());
            }

            StringBuilder sbResponseHeaders = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var item in context.Response.Headers)
            {
                sbResponseHeaders.AppendLine(item.Key + ": " + item.Value.ToString());
            }


            string filename = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd.HHmmss.fff") + "_" + httpStatus + "_" + cleanRoute + ".log";
            StringBuilder sbLog = new StringBuilder();
            sbLog.AppendLine("Status: " + httpStatus + " - Route: " + route);
            sbLog.AppendLine("=============");
            sbLog.AppendLine("Request Headers:");
            sbLog.AppendLine(sbRequestHeaders.ToString());
            sbLog.AppendLine("=============");
            sbLog.AppendLine("Request Body:");
            sbLog.AppendLine(requestBody);
            sbLog.AppendLine("=============");
            sbLog.AppendLine("Response Headers:");
            sbLog.AppendLine(sbResponseHeaders.ToString());
            sbLog.AppendLine("=============");
            sbLog.AppendLine("Response Body:");
            sbLog.AppendLine(responseBody);
            sbLog.AppendLine("=============");

            var path = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string filepath = ($"{path}\\Logs\\{filename}");
            File.WriteAllText(filepath, sbLog.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // It cannot cause errors no matter what
        }

    }
}

public class EnableRequestRewindMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public EnableRequestRewindMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Request.EnableRewind();
        await _next(context);
    }
}

public static class EnableRequestRewindExtension
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseEnableRequestRewind(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<EnableRequestRewindMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Startup.cs (existing file)

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IMapper mapper, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    bool isLogEnabled = true; // Replace it by some setting, Idk

    if(isLogEnabled)
        app.UseEnableRequestRewind(); // Add this first

    (...)

    if(isLogEnabled)
        app.UseMiddleware<AutoLogMiddleWare>(); // Add this just above UseMvc()

    app.UseMvc();
}
```