# How to create a web Api have http post function which can take any dynamic json content from body and able to parse it into string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an third party event that post data to my hosted API but the problem is I don't know the Json structure which event posting to my API from Body. I need to read the json content posted by Event to my API.
I have tried to create post method as dynamic or string type the event able to call the service but data is not get typecast, it shows null always.

```
[HttpPost]
RecievedPayload([FromBody]dynamic json) 
{  
}

[HttpPost]
RecievedPayload([FromBody]string json) 
{ 
}
```

RecievedPayload Api method is getting invoked by Third party Event but the json content is null. I need to know the Json structure so that I can make a custom class to hold the content.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479094/how-to-auto-log-every-request-in-net-core-webapi) for some tips on intercepting the raw request if Adam's answer doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a simple way to just get the whole body as a parameter.

This blog post is worth a full read: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/dec/13/accepting-raw-request-body-content-with-aspnet-web-api

However to accomplish your goal, this is a slightly modified version of a code sample provided in the blog post, which should work for your needs:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<string> RecievedPayload()
{
    string result = await Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();            
    return result;
}
```

Also worth reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api

Comment: The name of an argument does not matter, it is the properties of the Type of the argument that get model bound.

Comment: You're right, I misinterpreted something I read on the second link. Edited the answer accordingly