# HttpContext.Request is blank for a middleware running on AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-api-gateway, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .Net Core webapi that i have deployed on the AWS API Gateway. I created a middleware to process all incoming requests and outgoing responses. That middleware works perfectly fine on any local machine, which means, before http request hits my api controller, it goes through that middleware and being processed there correctly, but when it is deployed to AWS API Gateway, context.Request is always blank...

Here is how the middleware is implemented

```
    public class RequestLoggingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public RequestLoggingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<RequestLoggingMiddleware>();
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, IRequestLogger requestLogger)
    {
         // this line prints  In coming Raw Request ..... Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpRequest 
        _logger.LogInformation($"In coming Raw Request .....  {context.Request}");

         // this line prints  Request.ContentLength .....           
        _logger.LogInformation($"Request.ContentLength .....  {context.Request.ContentLength}");

         // this line prints   Request.Body ..... System.IO.MemoryStream                
        _logger.LogInformation($"Request.Body .....  {context.Request.Body}");
    }
}
```

**This is how it is configured in startup.cs Configure method**

```
            app.UseMiddleware<RequestLoggingMiddleware>();
```

Some more infomration regarding the issue.

**-How this is configured on the API gateway?** 
 it is configured as Proxy+

```
        "Events": {
          "ProxyResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
              "Path": "/{proxy+}",
              "Method": "ANY"
            }
       },
        "RootResource": {
            "Type": "Api",
            "Properties": {
                "Path": "/",
                "Method": "ANY"
                }
            }
        }
```

- **Are you deploying the middleware as a lambda?** 
  No the middleware is a typical .NEt MVC middleware configured in startup.cs like

  app.UseMiddleware();

  **- Are you performing any request mapping on the gateway?**

No

**- Is your eventual endpoint being invoked when you invoke the API gateway endpoint?**

Yes and it does get the request object correctly... Its just that middleware where i am not getting the body part of the request. On my local computer or one one of my teammate's computer it works fine.

Comment: i even tried an implementation from here... Same problem... in middleware the context.Request is always empty when the code is running on AWS API Gateway, on local machine it works fine.. https://salslab.com/a/safely-logging-api-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core

Comment: What do you mean exactly by `blank`?

Comment: that means context.Request.ContentLength is empty ....

Comment: What request you are sending to your API when you have `context.Request.ContentLength == null`? Is it `GET` or `POST`?

Comment: The request type is "POST"

Comment: Does it actually has body? Can you show an example of your request?

Comment: Are you uploading huge file maybe?

Comment: Can you provide some more details on how this is configured on the API gateway? 
- What is the integration type? Are you deploying the middleware as a lambda?
- Are you performing any request mapping on the gateway?
- Is your eventual endpoint being invoked when you invoke the API gateway endpoint?

Comment: @mailtobash i added answers as part of the actual question