# How Do I Determine WebServer Type at Runtime in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: .net-core

Is there an easy way for C# to tell at runtime if a .NET Core WebSite is running under: Kestrel; IIS Express; Apache; Full Blown IIS; or, some other WebServer?

I may not be looking in the right places, but I'm not seeing the information in HttpContext.

**UPDATE: The HttpContext.Response.Headers Keys and Values are pretty scarce when I look at them.  I'm doing this inside a Filter to log connection information per:

[How to auto log every request in .NET Core WebAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479094/how-to-auto-log-every-request-in-net-core-webapi)

I'm not sure if the location where I'm checking the response headers has anything to do with the issue I'm experiencing or not.**

Comment: why do you need to know this?

Comment: @sommmen - Mainly for security reasons.  I know it's probably bad practice, but at this current moment, it's possible more than one WebServer may be running on the same physical machine.  Per update above, I'm auto-logging connection information and the like via a filter.

Comment: idk about bad practice, but asp.net is made to run without knowing the server implementation, so asp.net is more portable. You're now introducing logic that could make the application dependant on what server its running, which would be sad. I was trying to think with you on how we could work around that. I would internalise/comment the shit out of this though to make sure nobody would take this code and build upon it and make actual server dependanot code.

Comment: @sommmen - I just want to log the web server type (along with other pertinent info) for forensic purposes because I'm "paranoid".  I not planning on using the information to control application behavior unless it is to alert security somehow.

Comment: i see, well in that case i would personally rather log the hostname, processname and a persistant clientID (guid?). Ive also seen this approach in other tracking tools. That way youre not depending on this, but you're still getting all the info you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There does not seem to be builtin way, You could however recognize the windows process that the application runs in.

You can use `Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName` to get the name, and then recognize the following values, and return the appropriate server.

```
    w3wp.exe is IIS 6.0 and later.
    aspnet_wp.exe is earlier versions of IIS.
    iisexpress.exe is IISExpress.
    dotnet.exe is ASP.NET Core.
    inetinfo.exe is older ASP applications running in-process.
```

[source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-find-the-name-of-the-aspnet-process?view=vs-2019)

e.g.

```cs
ServerEnum GetRunningProcessManager()
{
    var procName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;

    Switch(procName)
    {
       case "w3wp.exe":
          return ServerEnum.IIS6Later;
       ...
       default:
          return ServerEnum.Unknown;
    }

}
```