# Wrong format of JSON data (Arduino) to .net Azure App service, getting code 415

Tags: json, azure, arduino

I would like to ask about sending data from arduino/esp to .net App service running on Azure.
I am sending JSON to API with "list" of measurements (simple JSON, Id and Value).

Over PostMan I don't have any issue, but over Arduino I am facing issue that I receive result code 415.
Data are sent in JSON.

Arduino Code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char* ssid = "*******";
const char* password = "*******";

  
//Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
const char* serverName = "https://********.azurewebsites.net/api/Measurements/";

unsigned long lastTime = 0;
// Set timer to 5 seconds (5000)
unsigned long timerDelay = 5000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  Serial.println("Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.");
}

void loop() {

 
  //Send an HTTP POST request every 10 minutes
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED)
    {
      std::unique_ptr<BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure>client(new BearSSL::WiFiClientSecure);
      client->setInsecure();
     
      HTTPClient https;

      https.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); // tried even "text/json"
      //https.addHeader("Content-Length", "32"); 
      https.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
      https.addHeader("Host","******.azurewebsites.net");  
      https.addHeader("Cache-Control","no-cache");  
     
      String httpRequestData = "[{\"SensorId\": 1, \"Value\": 77.7}]"; 
      
      if (https.begin(*client, serverName)) 
      {
          Serial.print("[HTTPS] POST...\n");
          int httpCode = https.POST(httpRequestData);

          if (httpCode > 0) 
          {
            // HTTP header has been send and Server response header has been handled
            Serial.printf("[HTTPS] POST... code: %d\n", httpCode);

            // file found at server
            if (httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK || httpCode == HTTP_CODE_MOVED_PERMANENTLY) 
            {
              String payload = https.getString();
              Serial.println(payload);
            }
            else
            {
              Serial.printf("[HTTPS] POST... failed, error: %s\n", https.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
            }
          }
          else 
          {
              Serial.printf("[HTTPS] POST... failed, error: %s\n", https.errorToString(httpCode).c_str());
          }
          
          https.end();
    }
    else 
    {
      Serial.printf("[HTTPS] Unable to connect\n");
    }
   }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Not receiving any error, just response code 415.

> The HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type client error response code indicates that the server refuses to accept the request because the payload

JSON text:

> [{"SensorId": 1, "Value": 77.7}]

AppInsight:
[image]

PostMan successful request:
[image]
body of request in Postman:

[image]

And report from AppInsight:

[image]

App service:

[image]

Over PostMan I am able to reach azure and send data, but over Arduino I am not able to send data (I am able to get data, but not post)

Probably some beginner mistake.
Can someone give me hint?
Do I have wrong format of JSON?

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. I suggest you log your request in your azure app. From there you can see what is different between arduino and postman requests. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/67510839/5964792

Comment: What if you use this: `https.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");`. You are are posting JSON, I would assume you should accept it as well. I don't see that in your request.